# WinXP isnt on the boot screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-xp

I tried to boot into Windows XP and noticed that it wasn't in the boot menu. Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: Duplicated post: http://askubuntu.com/q/88384/62483

Comment: @Lucio That's probably the wrong master question. That's for getting Ubuntu bootable again after installing Windows, not the other way around. The technique there only rarely works for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo update-grub` if you haven't tried that lately. It may fix this.

Comment: @minerz029 Please don't be fooled by the question mark. This was offering a possible solution intended to solve the problem. I've edited it to make that clearer, but (besides my addition of `sudo`) there's not substantive difference in message, and it's clearly an answer now.

Comment: i ran the sudo command and still wasnt showing up